# PySimpleGUI - Login Authenticator

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm having trouble getting the login authenticator to work. Everything works fine except the login() function. The other two functions progress_bar() and create_account() are running without a problem. I keep getting a **KeyError: '-username-'** message. I've tried everything, even not using functions, and still. I can't find the issue. Anyone? @MacItaly

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

#PROGRESS BAR
def progress_bar():
    sg.theme('LightBlue2')
    layout = [[sg.Text('Creating your account...')],
            [sg.ProgressBar(1000, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progbar')],
            [sg.Cancel()]]

    window = sg.Window('Working...', layout)
    for i in range(1000):
        event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
        if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        window['progbar'].update_bar(i + 1)
    window.close()


def create_account():
    sg.theme('LightBlue2')
    layout = [[sg.Text("Sign Up", size =(15, 1), font=40, justification='c')],
             [sg.Text("E-mail", size =(15, 1),font=16), sg.InputText(key='-email-', font=16)],
             [sg.Text("Re-enter E-mail", size =(15, 1), font=16), sg.InputText(key='-remail-', font=16)],
             [sg.Text("Create Username", size =(15, 1), font=16), sg.InputText(key='-username-', font=16)],
             [sg.Text("Create Password", size =(15, 1), font=16), sg.InputText(key='-password-', font=16, password_char='*')],
             [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Cancel")]]

    window = sg.Window("Sign Up", layout)

    
    while True:
        event,values = window.read()
        if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        else:
            if event == "Submit":
                if values['-email-'] != values['-remail-']:
                    sg.popup_error("Error", font=16)
                    continue
                elif values['-email-'] == values['-remail-']:
                    progress_bar()
                    break
    window.close()
create_account()


def login():
    sg.theme("LightBlue2")
    layout = [[sg.Text("Log In", size =(15, 1), font=40)],
            [sg.Text("Username", size =(15, 1), font=16),sg.InputText(key='-usrnm-', font=16)],
            [sg.Text("Password", size =(15, 1), font=16),sg.InputText(key='-pwd-', password_char='*', font=16)],
            [sg.Button('Ok'),sg.Button('Cancel')]]

    window = sg.Window("Log In", layout)

    while True:
        event,values = window.read()
        if event == "Cancel" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        else:
            if event == "Ok":
                if values['-usrnm-'] == values['-username-'] and values['-pwd-'] == values['-password-']:
                    sg.popup("Welcome!")
                    break
                elif values['-usrnm-'] != values['-username-'] and values['-pwd-'] != values['-password-']:
                    sg.popup("Invalid login. Try again")

    window.close()
login()
```

Comment: I just happened across this, unfortunately, the tag in the post doesn't actually 'tag' me. I'll start looking at this now...

Comment: Okay, so you are creating 2 separate windows (both called 'window') and referencing keys ('-usrnm-' and 'username') from the two windows. When the first create_account() window closes you lose the values stored in those keys. You're receiving a KeyError because when the login() function is open, you only have access to values['-usrnm-'] and values['-pwd-']. The other keys, values['-username-'] and values['-password-'] are gone.

Comment: Do you know of any resource I can learn the ins and outs of coding with events? Everything I see is just teaching how to build GUI, but it doesn't show how to link events with the code. It's so frustrating... @MacItaly

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I have been using PySimpleGUI for a couple of years now and feel pretty comfortable with it. I learned everything I know from the PySimpleGUI documentation website and from the PySimpleGUI Github. Both are great resources for figuring out event definitions.

Comment: Just trying to learn it. Some things are pretty clear, but a lot of stuff is confusing or simply there isn't an explanation or example. They just tell you about the statement or method but don't exactly explain how to do it. For instance, right now I'm trying to get a list printed onto a multiline window, and yet no explanation. @MacItaly

Comment: Check out the PySimpleGUI GitHub. He's usually really good about responding to problems and assisting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `values['-password-']` after closing windows gui. you have to store username and password in variable. by using variable you can verify username and password at login function.

Try this :

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


username = ''
password = ''
#PROGRESS BAR
def progress_bar():
    sg.theme('LightBlue2')
    layout = [[sg.Text('Creating your account...')],
            [sg.ProgressBar(1000, orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progbar')],
            [sg.Cancel()]]

    window = sg.Window('Working...', layout)
    for i in range(1000):
        event, values = window.read(timeout=1)
        if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        window['progbar'].update_bar(i + 1)
    window.close()


def create_account():
    global username, password
    sg.theme('LightBlue2')
    layout = [[sg.Text("Sign Up", size =(15, 1), font=40, justification='c')],
             [sg.Text("E-mail", size =(15, 1),font=16), sg.InputText(key='-email-', font=16)],
             [sg.Text("Re-enter E-mail", size =(15, 1), font=16), sg.InputText(key='-remail-', font=16)],
             [sg.Text("Create Username", size =(15, 1), font=16), sg.InputText(key='-username-', font=16)],
             [sg.Text("Create Password", size =(15, 1), font=16), sg.InputText(key='-password-', font=16, password_char='*')],
             [sg.Button("Submit"), sg.Button("Cancel")]]

    window = sg.Window("Sign Up", layout)

    while True:
        event,values = window.read()
        if event == 'Cancel' or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        else:
            if event == "Submit":
                password = values['-password-']
                username = values['-username-']
                if values['-email-'] != values['-remail-']:
                    sg.popup_error("Error", font=16)
                    continue
                elif values['-email-'] == values['-remail-']:
                    progress_bar()
                    break
    window.close()
create_account()


def login():
    global username,password
    sg.theme("LightBlue2")
    layout = [[sg.Text("Log In", size =(15, 1), font=40)],
            [sg.Text("Username", size =(15, 1), font=16),sg.InputText(key='-usrnm-', font=16)],
            [sg.Text("Password", size =(15, 1), font=16),sg.InputText(key='-pwd-', password_char='*', font=16)],
            [sg.Button('Ok'),sg.Button('Cancel')]]

    window = sg.Window("Log In", layout)

    while True:
        event,values = window.read()
        if event == "Cancel" or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
        else:
            if event == "Ok":
                if values['-usrnm-'] == username and values['-pwd-'] == password:
                    sg.popup("Welcome!")
                    break
                elif values['-usrnm-'] != username or values['-pwd-'] != password:
                    sg.popup("Invalid login. Try again")

    window.close()
login()
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks a lot! Do you know of any resource I can learn the ins and outs of coding with events? Everything I see is just teaching how to build GUI, but it doesn't show how to link events with the code. It's so frustrating... @Bhargav Desai